# How to create a table in a particular database?

Tags: mysql, database, create-table

The create database statement is:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
    column_name1 data_type,
    column_name2 data_type,
    column_name3 data_type,
    ....
)
```

But I'm wondering how can I create a table in a specific database?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can specify the DB Name in the same query:

`CREATE TABLE database_name.table_name ( column_name1 data_type, column_name2 data_type, column_name3 data_type, .... )`

Comment: Also don't forget the table schema name `database_name.schema_name.table_name`for example, `mydatabase.dbo.mytable`.

Answer (score 21):

`USE dbname;`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/use.html

Comment: This is especially useful if you need to run the same query for multiple databases, that way you dont have to edit every single sql statement.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this query. 
Suppose the database name `schoolmanagementsystem`, table name `student`, and table columns name are `student_id`, `student_first_name`, and `student_last_name`.

So you can create a table (`student`) in a particular database (`schoolmanagementsystem`) following this way.

```
CREATE TABLE schoolmanagementsystem.student
(
    student_id int(10) not null,
    student_first_name varchar(20) not null,
    student_last_name varchar(20)not null
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create table inside a particular database as below:

```
CREATE TABLE database_name.table_name_();

CREATE TABLE library_database.book
(
    book_id int(10) not null,
    book_name varchar(20) not null,
    author_name varchar(20)not null
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have more than one database, in mysql, you can do `SHOW DATABASES` to view them all and then `USE` with your db name to make it the current one. Running `CREATE TABLE` will then create the table in that database.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT *
  FROM information_schema.TABLES  where table_schema ='database_name'
ORDER BY `TABLES`.`CREATE_TIME` DESC